# Documentation of geth commands

Tags: go-ethereum

I used to refer [management APIs](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-API) and [Geth Wiki Page](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth) to check geth commands, their parameters, options and everything. But this link seems not updated.

I can see multiple commands in geth console, which are not there in wikki page, like

- eth.resend
- personal.openWallet
- eth.namereg
- personal.listWallets etc.

Where can I find documentaion of same?

Answer (score 0):

if you have geth installed on your machine please type geth --help in your terminal command and you should receive the following commands from this repo.

https://github.com/conwise18/Geth-commands/tree/master

They are all the go-ethereum node commands available.

Unless you want to refer to the web3 commands and if so please see https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API

Comment: geth -h gives geth commands usually the flags used with geth. I can not any commands I asked in question with this and same for Javascript-APIs

Comment: That's because the commands you're trying to access to do exists or work.

Comment: for example you're trying personal.openWallet which is "personal.unlockAccount" and personal.listWallets is "eth.accounts"

Comment: NO. Not same. They may produce similar output but are not same. If they are same, why 2 commands? And even if they are same, where I can see that, any documentation? on what url means? What are params of `resendTransaction`? etc etc etc

Comment: Sorry dude, was only trying to help!